# jQuery AJAX POST not passing data to a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i have this jQuery:

```
$("#dropbin").droppable(
    {
    accept: '#dragme', 
    hoverClass: "drag-enter",
    drop: function(event) 
    {
      var noteid = "<?=isset($_POST['noteid']) ? $_POST['noteid'] : "" ?>";

      if (confirm('Delete the note?')==true) 
      {
        $('#dragme').hide();
        debugger
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: noteid,
          datatype: 'json',
          url: 'deleteNote.php',
          success: function(result)
              {
                  alert("Success");
              }
        });

        window.location = "http://discovertheplanet.net/general_notes.php";
      }
      else
      {
        window.location = "http://discovertheplanet.net/general_notes.php";
      }
    }
  });
```

and that includes this url: `url: 'deleteNote.php',`

in deleteNote.php:

```
<?php

include "connectionDetails.php";

?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) 
{
    // $noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];

    echo "You finally hit this bit, congratulations...";

    // $stmt = "UPDATE Notes SET Deleted = GETDATE() WHERE NoteID = (?)";
    // $params = $noteid2;

    // $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt, $params);

    // if ($stmt === false) 
    // {
    //  die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    // }

}

else
{
    echo "No Data";
}


?>
```

Now even in the URL if i run /deleteNote.php?noteid=25 it hits the "No Data" part of my PHP.

When i run in debugger it populates the variable noteid with a NoteID so that bit is working but the PHP file is saying its not set?

Comment: It will run "no data" when you run `/deleteNote.php?noteid=25` because that's a GET setting, not a POST which is what your code is looking for.

Comment: Are you getting the alert("Success"); by the way?

Comment: Yes i get the success alert, edit: also i have tried GET as well as i wasn't sure and that returned no data

Comment: `data: noteid,` is missing a key.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I have and thats where i saw the noteid being populated with an id from the database/the library is included/there are no errors/yes its on a web server

Comment: You constructed your ajax call slightly wrong, as Jon said. Look at my answer for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look in your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: noteid,
      datatype: 'json',
      url: 'deleteNote.php',
      success: function(result)
          {
              alert("Success");
          }
    });
```

Looks nice, but you are sending post data with no id, you're just sending a value. Try this instead.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          noteid: noteid
      },
      datatype: 'json',
      url: 'deleteNote.php',
      success: function(result)
          {
              alert("Success");
          }
    });
```

Comment: i have made this alteration but its still not working, still hitting the no data part

Comment: Your deletenote.php still has `if (isset($_POST['noteid']))`?

Comment: Yes, also i've noticed its not hitting my debugger now though?

Comment: Still hitting the alert?

Comment: ok not sure what happened there but its hitting the debugger and alert as it was before however still not hitting that php :( i have also uncommented out the PHP in the file so it should now update the item in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150321/discussion-between-willparky93-and-luke-litherland).